# How to debug this buggy variable assignment in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh, variable, variable-substitution

How can I find what’s causing this weird behavior?

```
~ mary@advv
$ hsdhh() a=evil

~ mary@advv
$ echo "$a"
evil

~ mary@advv
$ a=good

~ mary@advv
$ echo "$a"
evil
```

**Update**: I have found that `eval "$(fasd --init auto)"` causes this bug and filed an [issue](https://github.com/clvv/fasd/issues/142). Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `zsh 5.3.1`, the first `echo` returns nothing.

Comment: @Panki I’m using zsh 5.7.1. I’ve tested this on two machines with this same version, same bug.

Comment: Is `hsdhh` the actual name of the function you tested with?

Comment: @marcolz yes, I was trying to define a nonexistent function to set the variable a.

Comment: Can you try when you start with an empty environment, like with: `env - zsh -f`

Comment: @marcolz Yeah, it is not present in zsh -f ... weird

Comment: You never actually ran the function, so whatever set the variable isn't related to anything shown here.

Comment: Try again after running `set -x`. Maybe that's give you a clue. Do you have an alias for `hsdhh`? For instance, that behaviour could be explained if you had a `alias hsdhh=precmd`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This behavior happens with any random function name. My dotfiles are more than a thousand line of code, so set -x and the like are not an option. I think I’ll just use the f() { } syntax from now on, since that’s not buggy.

Comment: Why can't you use `set -x` before running those commands?

Comment: What do you get in `$a` if you replace `a=evil` with `a=$funcstack`?

Comment: Some code that tries to set the terminal title to indicate the running command, maybe? The bug is very likely to be in your dot files, and only you know what's in them. If you have no idea where the bug is, do a binary search (back up the file, comment out the second half, try, if you can reproduce the problem then comment out the second half of what remains else uncomment the first half of what's commented out, etc.)

Comment: Can you reproduce this with other variable names? What's the output of `a=good; echo $a`? Of `typeset -p a`? What do you see after running `set -x` at the shell prompt and trying again?

Comment: @Gilles I found the bug; See the update.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I found the bug; See the update.

Comment: Good find. Maybe you can add the result of your investigation as an answer once the question has been reopened (@Jeff)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I will abstain from voting to reopen for now, since the reopen queue voters have decided to leave this closed. My opinion is that the question as it stands has no indication that would lead any answerer to the fasd code/typo. Doubly so, since it was a typo/logic error in the code in the first place, making this a very temporarily-useful question/answer (since it may have been repaired in the code).

Comment: @JeffSchaller, that `fasd` is packaged in Debian/Ubuntu and the bug is still there there.

Comment: I'd be happy to help reopen this question if it could mention that it brings in that package (and perhaps list the Debian and/or fasd package version).

Comment: @JeffSchaller The original question was unanswerable, but “How can I debug what’s causing it?” is answerable.

Comment: @HappyFace Congratulations on finding the problem and a solution! As written, your question is asking "How can I debug what’s causing it?"; do you want to have *that* question answered, or would you rather update the question to ask "What's causing this?" (since you've found the answer to the latter). Please ping me via `@jeff-schaller` either way so that we can re-open the question appropriately. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think the question is really about the debugging process, and that was what ultimately helped me find the problem. I don’t know how to update the question to reflect that though? Do I just ask “How do I do debug this?” Feel free to edit it as you see fit, too.

Comment: My main concern is that the question is "answered" with the GitHub issue, if that's not the real Question. I will reopen it as-is so that debugging steps can be described. My only suggestion for an edit to the question would be de-emphasize the discovery of the bug/issue so that the focus remains on the troubleshooting aspect. Thank you for your patience in sorting this out!

Answer (score 1):

Zsh runs some code before and after each command. This is commonly used to update the prompt and the terminal title. It's likely that some of this code is buggy and modifying the variable `a` (if this only happens with `a`) or is sometimes evaluating part of the command line when it shouldn't (if this happens with every variable name).

Check your [hook functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions) and [debug trap](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-TRAPDEBUG):

```
which precmd
which preexec
which zshaddhistory
print -l $precmd_functions
print -l $preexec_functions
print -l $zshaddhistory_functions
which TRAPDEBUG
trap | grep DEBUG
```

Another way to get an idea of what's going on is to enable [tracing](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-XTRACE).

```
~ mary@advv
$ set -x
+ …
~ mary@advv
$ a=good
+ …
~ mary@advv
$ echo "$a"
evil
```

The code that appears instead of `…` is the hooks I mentioned above, and some part of that must be the culprit.

One experiment that may narrow it down is:

```
~ mary@advv
$ a=good; echo "$a"
```